# Is it possible to 'Update' Ui components before the 'Action' method is finished?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Command Button that calls an Action method and updates other related UI components:

```
<p:commandButton  value="Commit" action="#{controller.persist}" process="@this" update=":form:buttons :dateCommittedText" />
```

Inside the Action method, values are persisted to the database:

```
public void persist() {
    databaseService.save(some item);
    status = "Committed";
}
```

Is it possible for `update=":form:buttons :dateCommittedText"` to  be updated before the item is finished being persisted to the database?

Currently database transactions take a few seconds, and this pause makes my app feel very unresponsive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `p:remoteCommand` for that,

```
<p:commandButton  value="Commit" action="#{controller.onlyMinorChanges}" 
    process="@this" update=":form:buttons :dateCommittedText" 
    onsuccess="doAfter()"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="doAfter" action="#{controller.persist}"/>
```

And in your bean:

```
public void onlyMinorChanges() {
    status = "Committed";
}

public void persist() {
    databaseService.save(some item);
}
```

---

Unrelated:

about the unresponsive, take a look at this [AJAX Status](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatusHome.jsf)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand but this is how you can update a component from a bean.

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(":componentId");
```